# Reload environment variables inside powershell window

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

In my Powershell script I'm setting machine-level environment variables with:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_VARIABLE", "MY_VALUE", "Machine")`

Inside this same script, I am calling another application that will look for the variable above.  Is there a way for me to reload the current session with the variables I created above?

Answer (score 3):

No but you can also set the environment variables for the current process i.e. $env:MY_VARIABLE = 'MY_VALUE'.  Any application you start should inherit the environment variables set in this fashion.